# Error: identifier expected in Java

Tags: java, instance-variables

I am a new learner of Java. I learned some of the Java core concepts. I got the identifier expected error when run my following code:

```
class Sekar {
  public static int i,j,k;
  i = 900;
  static void max()
  {
    j = 100;
    if(i>j)
    {
      k=i;
    }
    else {
      k=j;
    }
    System.out.println("The maxmimum vale between"+i+"and"+j+"is :"+k);
  }               
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     max();       
  }
}
```

When I compile my code, I get the following error:

```
error: identifier expected
  i    =  900;
     ^
```

1. Can any one explain why this error happens here?
2. When I google about identifier expected error, I found that this error happens when variables are declared without datatype, but I declared that for all my variables i,j,k.
3. When I redeclare the data type again while setting value to "i" like `int i = 900` it works. Why does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i = 900;
```

This is a statement in Java, it can be inside Constructor or method, or initialization block.

In your case, you may move that inside the `max()` method

> When I re declare the data type again while setting value to "i" like
>   `int i = 900` it works. Why does it?

Here, you are declaring and assigning the value to the variable in the same time, same line.

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for more details and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) about java statements, expressions

> **Statements**
>
> Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A
>   statement forms a complete unit of execution. The following types of
>   expressions can be made into a statement by terminating the expression
>   with a semicolon (;).
>
> - Assignment expressions
> - Any use of ++ or --
> - Method invocations
> - Object creation expressions

Comment: you mentioned i = 900; is a statement and it should be inside method.

Comment: but you mean ? int i = 900; is not a statement .

Comment: yeah i got it in "int i = 900" , here the int object is initialized ,so it is an expression. thanks Kugathasan .

Answer (score 2):

Hava a look at [Java: Identifier expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559539/java-identifier-expected) :

```
i = 900;
```

is a statement as any other. You can't write statement anywhere. It must be in methods/constructors body. Initializing variable in declaration is called [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_%28computer_programming%29) and is exception to this rule.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

If you want to initialize static variable you can do it 2 (sane) ways:
Initialize variable right where you are declaring it:

```
class Sekar {
  public static int i = 900, j,k;

  static void max()
  {
    j = 100;
    if(i>j)
    {
      k=i;
    }
    else {
      k=j;
    }
    System.out.println("The maxmimum vale between"+i+"and"+j+"is :"+k);
  }               
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     max();       
  }
}
```

or do it in static constructor:

```
class Sekar {
  public static int i, j,k;

  static {
    i = 900;
  }

  static void max()
  {
    j = 100;
    if(i>j)
    {
      k=i;
    }
    else {
      k=j;
    }
    System.out.println("The maxmimum vale between"+i+"and"+j+"is :"+k);
  }               
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     max();       
  }
}
```

Also, if you want to define a [constant](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077549/learn-java/java-tip-5--java-constants.html) I recommend using final keyword.

j could be converted to [local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable).

```
class Sekar {
  public static final int I = 900;

  static void max()
  {
    int k;
    int j = 100;
    if(I>j)
    {
      k=I;
    }
    else {
      k=j;
    }
    System.out.println("The maxmimum vale between"+I+"and"+j+"is :"+k);
  }               
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     max();       
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah now i can understand the different between statement and definition. And how to declare the instance variables in right way . Thank you for your detailed answer Nitematojak.

Comment: Last example will not compile. `I != i`.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry. I forgot to change every occurance of "i" to "I".

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is this:

```
class Sekar {
    public static int i=900,j=100,k;
    static void max()
    {
        if(i>j)
        {
            k=i;
        }
        else {
            k=j;
        }
        System.out.println("The maxmimum vale between"+i+"and"+j+"is :"+k);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        max();
    }
}
```

However I would discourage you from using static fields in this case. I would suggest you to make `i`, `j` and `k` parameters to your method. And give them descriptive names while you're at it.

Also note that `k` is not initialised explicitly and is therefore set to `0` by default, so your `else` clause is never reached.