# Illegal start of expression inside if statement using objects

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

I'm having a very frustrating issue at the moment and perhaps the answer lies here?

I'm currently having an issue with if statements.
I want my core.java class to contain an if statement which closes the entire program if my variable counter reaches 2.

```
private int counter = 0;
//located in the class Ending
```

I implemented that using a seperate method `addCounter()`
which goes as

```
public void addCounter(){
    this.counter ++;
}
//this will be called in core.java
```

I also have a `getter` which is supposed to return the value of counter

```
public int getCounter(){
    return counter;
}
//this will be called in core.java
```

Decleration of changeState in core.java

```
Ending changeState = new Ending();
//(As per request)
```

***The real issue is described here:***

I can't seem to come up with a fitting if statement which checks if the method getCounter has reached '2' after `addCounter();`has been invoked several times

My first idea was to use something such as

```
if(changeState.getCounter().equals(2)){
System.exit(0);
}
//I also tried using: 

if(changeState.getCounter() == 2)

//however, that didn't work either
```

both lines give me numerous errors which I can't wrap my head around:

`.java:476: error: illegal start of type: if(changeState.getCounter().equals(2)){`

`.java:476: error: <identifier> expected: if(changeState.getCounter().equals(2)){`

`.java:476: error: ';' expected: if(changeState.getCounter().equals(2)){`

`.java:476: error: illegal start of type: if(changeState.getCounter().equals(2)){`

`.java:476: error: illegal start of type: if(changeState.getCounter().equals(2)){`

`.java:476: error: ';' expected: if(changeState.getCounter().equals(2)){`

Could anyone elaborate on what is going wrong and what should be done to overcome this issue?
Thank you in advance!

C.C.

Comment: `if (counter == 2)`?

Comment: This won't work since we're working with instances, you're trying to call upon counter which lies in the class Ending. This needs to be done in core.java

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In the first line (476?) it looks as if you're treating `counter` as an object that has callable methods, but it's just a primitive. What's the error you get from the second line, the one where you use the equality operator? Please post the entire class containing `counter`.

Comment: My mistake! It's late, I'll update my post, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Added to the post!

Comment: Is `changeState` in scope where you're trying to use it? Because it looks like it should work. What do you get if you try `if (changeState != null)`?

Comment: It seems that somehow everything gets messed up indentation wise... how odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[My answer lied here all along.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559539/java-identifier-expected)

If anyone else is having similar kind of issue, it seems that you simply can't invoke an object inside a class unless it's in a method.

I admit that this does solve my issue entirely, but it did show me a valuable lesson.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

.equals(2) is incorrect , the 2 in the equals method is a primitive **type** int literal not an Object or String **type**.

.equals() method uses either a **type** "String" 
counter.equals("2")

or it uses a **type** "object" to compare 
.equals(((Object)new String("2")))

If you must use .equals() method then it would be

```
if(counter.getCounter().equals(new Integer(2).toString())){
System.exit(0);
}
```

Although that really should be simpler such as

```
if(counter.getCounter() == 2){
System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The information I provided was erroneous, the object we're supposed to call here is changeState.getCounter.

Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: if(changeState.getCounter() == 2){
System.exit(0);
} 

also generated "illegal start of type of type" errors, asking for an <identifier> and semicolon