# Cannot resolve symbol 'execute' when executing AsyncTask

Tags: java

I have an AsyncTask code block that I need to execute, but it gives me some errors.

The errors I'm getting are:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'execute'

and:

> Unknown class: 'URL'

even though I have String "URL" declared. I'm pretty sure that the problem is that it cannot execute the `AsyncTask` somehow.

Here's the AsyncTask code that I need to execute:

```
package com.jasperhonkasalo.merenpinnankorkeusvsa;

        import android.os.AsyncTask;

        import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;
        import java.util.*;

        import javax.xml.namespace.*;
        import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
        import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
        import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Testclass {


    public static class NamespaceResolver implements NamespaceContext {
        private Document document;
        public NamespaceResolver(Document doc) {
            document = doc;
        }
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if (prefix.equals("")) {
                return document.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
            } else {
                return document.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
            }
        }
        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return document.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
        }
        public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Document createDocumentFromString(String xml) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    }



    public static class getAndReturnValues extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url.toString()).openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code that I'm trying to call the `AsyncTask` with:

```java
    String url = "http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs/fin?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::mareograph::timevaluepair&fmisid=134223&";
        public TestClass  myTask = new TestClass();
        myTask.execute(url)
```

Comment: I don't see any `execute` attempt in your main example but based on code after it: `public TestClass  myTask = new TestClass(); myTask.execute(url);` it looks like (since you used `public` which can appear only at class level) you are also trying to invoke `myTask.execute(url)` at class level. If that is the case then simply move `myTask.execute(url);` to some method or constructor or initialization block.

Comment: Thank you! This actually worked and solved my problem! If you could post it as an answer I'll accept it as a valid answer.

Comment: Sorry but since I needed to guess what the problem was I doubt that this question would be helpful for anyone facing same problem (since they would also need to guess if they are in same situation). Could you limit it to [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) (maybe not even related to Android) and provide *exact* error message? BTW if it happens that exact error message you are facing is `<identifier> expected` (which I am getting for similar problem) then maybe it should be marked as duplicate of [Java: Identifier expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10559539).

Comment: @Pshemo sorry, (I'm new to StackOverflow) but how can I mark this as a duplicate :D

Comment: There should be an option for that in `flag` section (although I am not sure if it is available for author of the question). Anyway I already marked it for you.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks, man!