# Void somehow cannot be called

Tags: java, methods, call, void

so I'm just getting into coding and I was searching up some youtube lessons on how to code. I was copy and pasted a code from a certain lesson about Objects and classes but I somehow can't get the void to be called. So i'm not sure if the problem lies in my placement or that I might be doing something wrong:

```
class Robot {
String name;
String color;
int weight;

Robot(String a, String b, int c) {
    this.name = a;
    this.color = b;
    this.weight = c;

}

Robot IO = new Robot ("Aikatsu", "Yellow", 20);
Robot AO = new Robot ("Sora", "Red", 50);


void Introduction() {
     System.out.println("Hey, My name is: " + this.name);
 }

    IO.Introduction();
    AO.Introduction();
```

}

I also tried searching the internet for answers but I cant seem to find a similar issue, or that I just don't know how to search properly.

Comment: Look for the definition of [void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type)

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559539/java-identifier-expected

Comment: @Joni, yeah it does... thanks!

Comment: @Luuk I'll go check it up, thanks for the suggestion!