# Why do I get a syntax error on array declaration?

Tags: java

I am new to Java; can someone please explain to me why this gives me an error

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token  InsertionSort.java  /Alghoritems/src/sort   line 4  Java Problem

```
package sort;

public class InsertionSort {
    int[] polje = { -2, 5, -14, 35, 16, 3, 25, -100 };
    
    for(int firstUnsorted = 1; firstUnsorted < polje.length; firstUnsorted++) {
        int newElement = polje[firstUnsorted];
        int i;
        for (i = firstUnsorted; i > 0 && polje[i - 1] > newElement; i--) {
            
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < polje.length; i++){
        int firstUnsorted = 1;
        int elemant;
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Your code is not inside a method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Identifier expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559539/java-identifier-expected)

Comment: Apart from the answers, I would recommend you to learn the basics of the language before doing any sorting. That would really help in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Java application needs an entry point, so the compiler knows where to begin executing the application. In the case of Java applications, you need to wrap up your code in the main() method.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

Your code should be

```
package sort;
    
public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[] polje = { -2, 5, -14, 35, 16, 3, 25, -100 };
        
        for(int firstUnsorted = 1; firstUnsorted < polje.length; firstUnsorted++) {
            int newElement = polje[firstUnsorted];
            int i;
            for (i = firstUnsorted; i > 0 && polje[i - 1] > newElement; i--) {
                
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < polje.length; i++){
            int firstUnsorted = 1;
            int elemant;
            
        }
        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write code in the main method,then the error will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand that Java is a programming language that is full on object-oriented. Even when you want to do the simplest thing, you have to create a class with a `main` method inside. I suggest you start with the basics, before going in for implementations of more difficult algorithms.

```java
package sort;

public class InsertionSort {
   
      public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] polje = { -2, 5, -14, 35, 16, 3, 25, -100 };

        for(int firstUnsorted = 1; firstUnsorted < polje.length; firstUnsorted++) {
            int newElement = polje[firstUnsorted];
            int i;
            for (i = firstUnsorted; i > 0 && polje[i - 1] > newElement; i--) {

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < polje.length; i++){
            int firstUnsorted = 1;
            int elemant;

        }
    }

}
```